# Snowflake Creating a List of Dates

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This code works perfectly in SSMS, but in Snowflake, not so much. Any suggestions on how I can fix it?

```
 set (start_date) = ('2017-07-01');
 set (end_date) = ('2022-06-30');

  with get_all_dates as (




      select 
        $start_date as DateValue
        , 1 as level
      union all
      select    
        DATEADD(DAY,1,DateValue)
        , level + 1
      from 
        get_all_dates
      where 
        Datevalue < $end_date
  
  )
  
  select * from get_all_dates;
```

This produces the following error message:

> SQL compilation error: Type mismatch between anchor and recursive term
> of column 'DATEVALUE' in Recursive CTE 'GET_ALL_DATES'

Expected output:

```
2017-07-01
2017-07-02
...
2022-06-29
2022-06-30
```

Comment: [Generating date ranges with ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76141254/5070879)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Gordon's answer is useful, but beware -- seq4() is not guaranteed to produce sequential numbers. That means you could get a series of disparate dates instead of the desired result.

You can do this instead:

```sql
select '2020-01-01'::date+x 
from (
  select row_number() over(order by 0) x 
  from table(generator(rowcount => 1824))
)
```

Shorter version:

```sql
select '2020-01-01'::date + row_number() over(order by 0) x 
from table(generator(rowcount => 1824))
```

With an arbitrary start_date and end_date:

```sql
select -1 + row_number() over(order by 0) i, start_date + i generated_date 
from (select '2020-01-01'::date start_date, '2020-01-15'::date end_date)
join table(generator(rowcount => 10000 )) x
qualify i < 1 + end_date - start_date
```

[image]

Comment: I am new to Snowflake, where does "SELECT" rank on this list: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html

I am trying to digest your query.

Comment: `SELECT` is a mix in this case. I introduced `qualify` because `generator(rowcount => 10000 )` will produce too many rows, so then I remove all the rows not within the date range. A subquery would have worked too instead of using `qualify`, but this is more compact.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a bunch of numbers and generate the dates based on that:

```
select dateadd(day, row_number() over (order by null), '2017-07-01')
from table(generator(rowcount => 1824)) g
```

Comment: Careful here! `seq4()` could produce non-sequential numbers. "This function uses sequences to produce a unique set of increasing integers, but does not necessarily produce a gap-free sequence."  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/seq1.html

Comment: @FelipeHoffa . . . If I use `row_number()`, what is the appropriate `order by`?  `order by seq4()`?  `order by NULL`?