# Combine each of n ids with m consecutive numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a set of `n` ids, say table 1, like so:

| id |
| --- |
| id_1 |
| id_2 |
| ... |
| id_n |

I would like to combine this with a set of numbers 1...m (m is medium large here, i.e. between a hundred and a thousand) to get a table that looks like this:

| id | number |
| --- | --- |
| id_1 | 1 |
| id_1 | 2 |
| ... | ... |
| id_1 | m |
| id_2 | 1 |
| ... | ... |
| id_2 | m |
| ... | ... |
| id_n | m |

That is the size of this, say table 2, is going to be m*n.

Is something like this possible in SQL? The dialect I am using is Snowflake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a cross join should work right?

Substituting "10" for m

```
SELECT IT.id,
       INT_SEQ.seq_val
  FROM ID_TABLE IT
 CROSS
  JOIN
       (select row_number() over(order by 0) AS seq_val
          from table(generator(rowcount => 10)) v 
       ) INT_SEQ
```

Comment: Careful: `seq4()` might not give sequential numbers, add some `row_number() over(order by 0)` there https://stackoverflow.com/a/66449068/132438

Comment: I guess I did not know about this generator think. This is snowflake right?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Great catch

Comment: @clog14 Yup, just tested it out

Comment: I'm glad error_2646 answer worked for you @clog14! Please remember to upvote and/or accept useful answers ;)

Comment: Have to still try it tomorrow but then will for sure do all these things ;-)