# Snowflake procedure with default datetime arguments

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, resultset

I'm looking to create a Snowflake procedure that would enable end user to create a table with a list of timestamps within defined period of specific interval.

### Example

The end-user passing arguments:

- `from_date` : `CURRENT_DATE() - 2`
- `to_date` : `CURRENT_DATE`
- `diff_factor` : `hour`

Should obtain table of 48 rows resembling the one below

| ID | ts |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mon, 18 Dec 2023 21:15:46 GMT *(Whatever equals CURRENT_DTE() - 2)* |
| 2 | Mon, 18 Dec 2023 22:15:46 GMT |
| ... | ... |

### Code

Within the code below the procedure receives two `DATETIME` arguments and falls back on `CURRENT_DATE` if not provided.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE generate_dates_table(
  from_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE() - 1, 
  to_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
  diff_factor STRING DEFAULT 'hour')
  RETURNS TABLE(id INTEGER, ts TIMESTAMP_NTZ)
  LANGUAGE SQL 
  COMMENT = 'Generate nice table with timestamps'
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
DECLARE
  res RESULTSET
  difference INTEGER DEFAULT 1 ;
BEGIN
  LET difference := (SELECT(DATEDIFF(:diff_factor, :from_date, :to_date))); 
  LET res : = (SELECT (SEQ4) AS id,
               DATEADD(:diff_factor, SEQ4() , :from_date) AS ts
               FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => :difference))));
RETURN TABLE(res); 
END


-- Test
CALL generate_dates_table();
```

### Errors

- Snowflake returns multiple error messages when trying to compile statement, such as unexpected `SELECT` and `SEQ4` statements

### Notes

- I'm mostly interested in working through Snowflake scripting and learning:

  - What's the appropriate way to handle date time arguments with default values as expression
  - How to store results of a query as a variable to used later in scripting? `difference` should return number of rows that can be later used by `GENERATOR` and timestamp calculations
  - Are there any other suggestions concerning the script structure
- I'm not interested in non-procedural solutions generating list of dates or timestamps, like the nifty answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66449068/1655567)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composable UDTF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_dates_table(
  from_date    DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE() - 1, 
  to_date      DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE(),
  diff_factor  STRING   DEFAULT 'hour'
)
RETURNS TABLE(id INTEGER, ts TIMESTAMP_NTZ)
AS
$$
  SELECT value::INT, DATEADD('HOUR', value::INT, from_date)
  FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(0, DATEDIFF('HOUR',from_date,to_date)+1)))
  WHERE diff_factor ILIKE 'hour'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT value::INT, DATEADD('DAY', value::INT, from_date)
  FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(0, DATEDIFF('DAY',from_date,to_date)+1)))
  WHERE diff_factor ILIKE 'day' 
  -- more dayparts go here
$$
```

Sample call:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(generate_dates_table());

SELECT *
FROM TABLE(generate_dates_table(diff_factor=>'DAY'));

SELECT *
FROM TABLE(generate_dates_table(from_date => '2023-12-05'::DATETIME,
                                to_date => '2023-12-19'::DATETIME,
                                diff_factor=>'DAY'));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the contribution, in what sense composable UDF is better than a procedure? Second question, there is no way to pass the diff_factor value as a variable so it would be possible to avoid the ILIKE statement, as diff_factor can take multiple values, nanosecond, etc. Iterating through all would be laborious.

Comment: @Konrad The code can be easily translated into SP, though SP that only returns a resultset is no different than UDTF(used here) plus `CALL sp_...()` cannot be easily used with other SQL constructs where UDFT can. Second `diff_factor` must be a constant for DATEADD/DATEDIFF functions that is why the ` WHERE diff_factor = ?` was used. You can use dynamic SQL to manually craft a SQL query (only SP) but be aware of possible SQL Injection as it is input from the user.