# Snowflake Generate row for every date between 2 date columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working in Snowflake trying to explode rows in a table where each row is currently based on a date range provided by `start_date` and `end_date` columns.  I need to turn this information into a single row for every date in that date range.

Below is my current table as of right now.  In this example there's a row with a date range that spans 5 days with a price of $5, so I want to turn this 1 row into 5 rows for every date in that date range while retaining that same pricing information of $5 for every row.

| start_date | end_date | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-22 | 2023-05-26 | 5 |

## Proposed Solution 1

| start_date | end_date | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-22 | 2023-05-22 | 5 |
| 2023-05-23 | 2023-05-23 | 5 |
| 2023-05-24 | 2023-05-24 | 5 |
| 2023-05-25 | 2023-05-25 | 5 |
| 2023-05-26 | 2023-05-26 | 5 |

## Proposed Solution 2

| date | price |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-22 | 5 |
| 2023-05-23 | 5 |
| 2023-05-24 | 5 |
| 2023-05-25 | 5 |
| 2023-05-26 | 5 |

Either solution will work for my use case.  In Postgresql i've used `generate_series` and had good results, but while researching this for Snowflake I'm not really seeing any great solutions so far.  Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [generate\_series() equivalent in snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348801/generate-series-equivalent-in-snowflake)

Comment: *I'm not really seeing any great solutions so far* - ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE makes it easy https://stackoverflow.com/a/76141254/5070879  MVE: `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(start_date DATE, end_date DATE, price INT) 
AS SELECT '2023-05-22', '2023-05-26', 5;

SELECT start_date + VALUE::INT AS date, price
FROM tab ,TABLE(FLATTEN(ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(0, DATEDIFF('DAY',start_date,end_date)+1)));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions!  Lukasz solution is perfect.  Much appreciated!

```
select
    date(start_date) + value::int as date,
    price
from pricing_table,
     table(flatten(array_generate_range(0, datediff('day', start_date, end_date) + 1)))
;
```

[image]